# BigBlueButton Customize the HTML 5 client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ubuntu, meteor, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to remove the three-dot options menu button in Big blue button HTML 5 client installed on ubuntu
Our implementation is done where the html5 client is shown inside a iframe, therefore i need to manage the meeting leave and meeting end functions out side the iframe.

Please help, been looking at this for days

Thank you!

Comment: +Following your question... I'm interested too

Answer (score 0):

@AjaxNash You could attach postMessage listener on the parent site and at the iframe login/logout, post event mentioning the user details.